# Global variable isn't accessible inside my Wordpress function. Why not?

Tags: php, wordpress, global-variables, php-include

I am working in wordpress, and have a function in functions.php. This is meant to set a number of variables based on the context the variable is used in. But there's a problem.

I am using the function in an included template file, and the function is intended to work with variables on the page that template file is included into. I declare all the variables as global inside my function, but the function doesn't recognize the values of the variables. I don't understand why this is happening, because I am certain that the variable scope is being used properly.

To clear up confusion, I have included a simplified code example below, showing the three files involved in this issue. If anybody has any idea why this is happening, I would be delighted to hear it. I am interested in understanding the reasons why it is happening, more than looking for a fix.

functions.php

```
function set_variables() {
    global $data;
    print_r($data);
}
```

included_file.php

```
set_variables();
(Code that sets other variables and works with HTML)
```

template_file.php

```
$data = "Test";
include "included_file.php";
```

The result of the code above is nothing--I can't get the function in functions.php to recognize the variable defined in template_file.php. However, if I define the $data variable in functions.php, it works.

Like I said, this baffles me since it seems to contradict how declaring global variables within a function is supposed to work. How am I getting it wrong?

Comment: Uhm... `set_variable()` and `set_variables()` are not the same thing

Comment: Is it really global? How do you know that? Btw, why do you need a global variable - why not pass it as an argument?

Comment: @Machavity - That is a mistake in creating the example--the code itself is fine, but verbose. I didn't want to paste a lot of code.

Comment: @zerkms - I declared the variable global inside the function, used the function in another file, and then included that file inside a template. I assumed that the variable declared in the template file would be global relative to the function call. Clearly I made a mistake somewhere, and don't know what it is.

Comment: @user3628576 for a variable to be global it must be declared as `global` **everywhere** it's used. Or it must be placed in a global scope. That simple, yep.

Comment: @zerkms - But now that you mention it, the code is used within a set of loops. I don't know of any reason that would affect scope, though--I call the function within a loop nested inside the loop where the variable is defined. Would that make a difference?

Comment: What makes difference if the current scope is global or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@zerkms - Thanks very much for answering my question. Turns out all I had to do was declare the variable as global in the file where it was defined.

So, in the example given above, the solution is as follows:

functions.php

```
function set_variables() {
    global $data;
    print_r($data);
}
```

included_file.php

```
set_variables();
(Code that sets other variables and works with HTML)
```

template_file.php

```
global $data = "Test";
include "included_file.php";
```

I just assumed that the variable declared in the template_file.php was in the global scope, but I suppose it wasn't. Still a bit fuzzy on the whys, but I know the code worked, and I'm really happy about that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you misspelled the calling function:

**set_variable() is not the same as set_variables()**

Please note the following from PHP about including files:

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: "included files enforces the global scope" --- that's not true.

Comment: Your edit is incorrect as well. Just read the last phrase of your quote carefully.

Comment: @Stephn_R - Thank you for the feedback, but that was a mistake on my part in creating the example. The code above is a simplified version of what is going on inside the file. Not my actual code. My question is directed at the phenomenon of a variable declared global inside a function not being available. I just tried to give a visual representation of the context in which the code is executing in an attempt to clarify the situation.